# Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Working on this Flash AS3 application and I am keep getting this error when I try to make an `imgLoader` clickable.

The imgLoader is a dynamic loader which will load an image from XML file and its created using ActionScript.

This is the full error I get:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at apptest_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[apptest_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:65]
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
    at runtime::AppRunner/run()
    at ADLAppEntry/run()
    at global/runtime::ADLEntry()
```

and this is the code for making the `imgLoader` clickable:

```
imgLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething);
function doSomething(event:MouseEvent){
nextFrame()
```

anyone knows why this is happening?

**EDIT**

This is my entire code:

```
stop();

import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Sprite; 
import flash.filters.DropShadowFilter; 

var xmlLoader11:URLLoader;
var xml11:XML;

var uRequest11 = new URLRequest("my.xml");
xmlLoader11 = new URLLoader(uRequest11);
xmlLoader11.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoad11);
var imgLoader11:Loader;
var nameLoader11:Loader;
var myString11:String = 'loading';

function onXMLLoad11(e:Event) {
    xml11 = new XML(e.target.data);
    imgLoader11 = new Loader();
    imgLoader11.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImgLoaded11);
    imgLoader11.load(new URLRequest(xml11.Data.Image.text()[0]));
    Nametxt11.text =  "" + xml11.Data.Name.text()[0];
}

function onImgLoaded11(e:Event) {
    addChild(imgLoader11);
    imgLoader11.height = 300;
    imgLoader11.width = 300;

    var bitmapContent11:Bitmap = Bitmap( e.target.content );
    bitmapContent11.smoothing = true;
    addChild( bitmapContent11 );
    bitmapContent11.height = 150;
    bitmapContent11.width = 150;
    bitmapContent11.y = 65;
    bitmapContent11.x = 85;
}
imgLoader11.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething);
function doSomething(event:MouseEvent){
nextFrame()
```

Comment: Add a statement that checks whether `imgLoader` is added or not.

Comment: Thanks David. how do I do that?

Comment: Attach `imgLoader11.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething);` at the end of `onXMLLoad11(e:Event)` and add an if statement for `doSomething(event:MouseEvent)`. Something like `if (imgLoader11 != null)`. AS3 is very picky when it comes to handling objects.

Answer (score 0):

Does it break when this is called:

```
imgLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething);
```

or when this is called:

```
nextFrame()
```

In the first case, imgLoader is null.  In the second case, something you're trying to acess fields or methods of right after nextFrame() is called is null.

EDIT:

Try moving this:

```
imgLoader11.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething);
function doSomething(event:MouseEvent){
nextFrame()
}
```

to the bottom of onXMLLoad11().

```
function onXMLLoad11(e:Event) {
    xml11 = new XML(e.target.data);
    imgLoader11 = new Loader();
    imgLoader11.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImgLoaded11);
    imgLoader11.load(new URLRequest(xml11.Data.Image.text()[0]));
    Nametxt11.text =  "" + xml11.Data.Name.text()[0];

    imgLoader11.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething);
    function doSomething(event:MouseEvent){
    nextFrame()
    }
}
```

Comment: it breaks after imgLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething);

Comment: Yeah, imgLoader's null.  You need to instantiate it.  Assuming the name of its class is ImageLoader, you need to call imgLoader = new ImageLoader(); or what have you ahead of time.  Or if it doesn't have a class, imgLoader = new Object();  If you have something like that in your code already, the problem is that the line of code it's being instantiated on is not being reached before the line of code where you're calling addEventListener().

Comment: Thanks mate, let me try that.

Comment: No, still no luck with it... I have updated my question with my entire code. any chance you could view it and let me know where I am going wrong please?